# create c# code of onclick function in aspx.cs

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

What I'm trying to do is to call a function in aspx.cs from aspx file.

**JavaScript code:** (for which I'm trying to make c# function in aspx.cs file)

```
function myconfirm() {

    var txt;
    var x = confirm("confirmation!!");
    if (x == true) {

        txt = " Your Request is Submitted!";
    }
    else {
        txt = "Verify and Confirm!";
    }
    document.getElementById("verify").innerHTML = txt;

    return false;
}
```

**c# code in aspx.cs:** (This is what I'm trying out and getting a error)

```
namespace TESTING
{
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    public void myconfirm(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string x = "confirmation!!";
        string txt;
        if (x == "true")
        {
            txt = "your request is submitted";
        }
        else
        {
            txt = "verify and confirm ";
        }
    }

        public void myconfirm1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string y="confirmation!!";
            string text;
            if(y=="true")
            {
                text="we are tracking your PRN";
            }
            else{
                text="verify and confirm!!";
            }
    }
}
}
```

**calling it from aspx file:**

```
<asp: Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="SUBMIT" OnClick="myconfirm"></asp: Button>
```

**error I'm getting**

> 'myconfirm1' is undefined"

**Summarising it**:

1. DEFINE A ONCLICK METHOD IN ASPX.CS FILE from c#.
2. calling it from aspx file.

**Problems occurring**:

1. lack of basic concept of how to exactly write the c# code in aspx.cs file.

*And also If anyone can give a brief concept of how to write c# code in aspx.cs to be called from aspx file.*

Comment: string x = "confirmation!!"; and then  if (x == "true") How ??

Comment: I don't know just m trying out...I have written above that I m lacking basic concepts of c#...I m studying it by my own nd making A web application...I know javascript and m quite good in "inline coding" but now m trying "code behind " for same...so plz help! @DhavalPatel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the below mentioned code

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">
    function Confirm() {
        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        if (confirm("Do you want to save data?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
        }
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
    }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="btnConfirm" runat="server" OnClick = "OnConfirm" Text = "Raise Confirm" OnClientClick = "Confirm()"/>
```

and your cs file look like

```
public void OnConfirm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
    if (confirmValue == "Yes")
    {
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('You clicked YES!')", true);
    }
    else
    {
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('You clicked NO!')", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: THANK U so much its Done !!and plz if u can answer one more question from basic that "When we need to create a new Namespace and how to write it correctly??" @DhavalPatel

Comment: @Shruti:if this answers is useful then don't forgot to accept it so other can use it

Comment: I have many textboxes in my page in which I have used "range validation" and as there will be only one SUBMIT BUTTON in my page, how can I use that single button for both calling above function as well as it should also keep check over the "Range validator" i.e no fields should be left blank /invalid entries????

Comment: you have to use validation group : http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showaspx.asp?filename=demo_prop_webcontrol_imagebutton_validationgroup

Comment: Thank u so much just two words and my problem is solved..I just had to add `causevalidation="true" validationgroup="valid"` in my asp:button description and its working perfectly..@DhavalPatel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54593/discussion-between-dhaval-patel-and-shruti).

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not wrong.  see below can help you up or not.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Confirmation() {
            var rowQuestion = confirm("Are you sure you want to confirm?");
            if (rowQuestion == false) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>
```

and the aspx will be:

```
<asp:Button Text="Confirm Training" OnClientClick="return Confirmation();" ID="btnConfirm"  OnClick="btnConfirm_Click" runat="server" />
```

confirm at the javascript "confirmation" first, then, only call the btnConfirm_click code behind.

Comment: thnks for ur effort but THE above code u have given can't be written in ASPX.CS file....I m trying to do "code behind" of the javascript I have given in my question. @Tan

Comment: @Shruti: you mean you want to call javascript from code behind?

Comment: <button onclick=" return myconfirm()" 
                    SUBMIT
                </button><p id="verify">
            </p>
            
            
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function myconfirm() {

        var txt;
        var x = confirm("confirmation!!");
        if (x == true) {

            txt = " Your Request is Submitted!";
        }
        else {
            txt = "Verify and Confirm!";
        }
        document.getElementById("verify").innerHTML = txt;

        return false;
    }
</script></div>`

Comment: above is my javascript code which I have written in aspx file and this is working perfectly but now I want to do same thing without these javascript code and in place of it writing a c# code in aspx.cs file .I hope now my question is clear! @DhavalPatel

Comment: you mean, even javascript you want to code it dynamically/static in codebehind, so that, you no need to have two kind of maintenance one in aspx and one in aspx.cs?

Comment: @MinHongTan:She don't want to use javascript she want all confirm stuff from code behind

Comment: Yaa sort of ..just one set of code and that only in c# in aspx.cs file in the place of JavaScript which I had previously used and then I can call that code behind from aspx file. @MinHongTan

Comment: XACTLYY ..thank u for clearing my question @DhavalPatel

Comment: @Shruti: but there is no sense doing that why you don't want javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you want to eliminate your JS code and do the logic in Code Behind File.

```
public void myconfirm(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string x = "confirmation!!";
        string txt;
        if (x == "true") // your code, I have no idea why you are doing it. You have set x to confirmation so it will never be true in first place. anyways!!
        {
            txt = "your request is submitted";
        }
        else
        {
            txt = "verify and confirm ";

        }

       Verify.Text = txt; // Verify is the label where you want to display your final result.
    }
```

Comment: I believe you are new to SO, so if you find an answer correct you mark it as correct and accept it :P
Also, you need to look for C# books first to get into C# programming